# Функция выделения текста в QLineEdit

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qlineedit

Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку "`Rename`" предлагалось изменить текст надписи в окне?

Comment: Почитать документацию

Comment: Опубликуйте модуль `.ui` или что там у вас уже написано и лучше расскажите на какую именно кнопку надо нажать, что именно вы собираетесь предложить для выбора изменения текста и куда именно надо поместить выбранные (или набранные? ) изменения.

Comment: Опубликуйте модуль `.ui` в теле вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код надо публиковать в теле вопроса. У меня нет доступа к вашему коду, но я вам покажу как это можно реализовать.

> void QLineEdit::[**selectAll**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#selectAll)()
>
> Выделяет весь текст (т.е. выделяет его) и перемещает курсор в конец. 
> Это полезно, когда было вставлено значение по умолчанию, потому что, если пользователь введет текст до нажатия на виджет, выделенный текст будет удален.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit('Имя') 
        
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('PushButton_Rename')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        
        
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 1)
        
    def on_clicked(self):
        self.lineEdit.selectAll()
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]